# ArrayList swap and remove last index in O(1)

Tags: java, arraylist, swap

So I want to implement a "remove random index from arraylist" method, but I am unsure if I am correct in my runtime.

I generate a random index within bounds, which is what I want to be removed, then I swap that index with the last and do remove on list.size()-1. I then conclude that this is done in O(1) time since swap should be O(1) and I essentially circumvent the shift that is otherwise needed.

There is no requirment to not change the order of the list, so swapping around is ok.

Am I correct in this?

Comment: Yes, sounds correct. You can use a debugger to step through the code to see exactly which statements are executed

Comment: Make sure to also check the complexity of `.size()` before declaring such operation to be O(1)